# Link to a location on another page, with an offset

Tags: html, href

How can I link to a div on another page, but with an offset of about 50px?

My issue here is that I have an element on a page that I link to from another page, for the sake of example let's call these page1.html and page2.html

page1.html has this:

```
<a href='$URL/page2.html#div'>Link</a>
```

When clicked, it takes me to page2.html and moves the page to the div, however I have a fixed header on all pages that is about 50px high, this covers the text that I wanted the link to take me to.

What would I need to do to have this link go to that div, with an offset of 50px?

I *CANNOT* simply add a margin or link to anything above this div.

Edit: I cannot modify page2.html, only page1.html.

Edit2: I have access to js/page2.js and css/page2.css, just not to page2.html

Comment: you cant change the code? Or you do not want to mess up the css?

Comment: I cannot modify page2.html, only page1.html

Comment: If the page is on another domain (not yours) - there is nothing you can do. If it is yours page and you have .js loading there which you can modify - then it is possible to do what you want.

Comment: After confirming, I am able to modify a js file that loads on that page, just not the page's html itself. js/page2.js is within my reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Only by making CSS changes on the second page.

Also i do not think a browser should let you to do it while you do not have access on the second page for security reasons (example: page centering inside iframes).

An easy way to fix this with css is by adding `margin-top:-40px;padding-top:40px;`

Comment: What form of css change would I have to make? I have access to that page's css file and js file, just not its actual html.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do via only link if you can't modify page2.

However you can to use jQuery to get code of some page, place it to some container and then scroll:

```
$("#element").load("page2.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  //Here should be code that places received html to your page and makes scroll
});
```

Another workaround is usage of browser plugins.
These realizations will be robust, so think one more time before implementation of it.